# How to generate an array of byte values that are within a specific range (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, random, byte

For an assignment, I need to generate an array of 100 randomly generated byte values that range from 0-10 (ex. {10, 2, 3, 2, 7, 5...} ). I have been able to generate the array of random byte values, but I have no idea how to have the values be between 0-10. This is what I have so far to generate the array:

```
byte[] array = new byte[100];
        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.nextBytes(array);

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by casting [Random.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to a `byte`, which returns a random number from 0 up to but not including the parameter.

```
byte[] array = new byte[100];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        array[i] = (byte) rand.nextInt(11);
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array));
```